# How to create a footer row for Tablix and repeat it in every page of report?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, rdlc, reportviewer2008

**I want to create a footer row for a Tablix**. To archive this, I have done some steps below:

- Insert a Tablix into body of report
- Create a row group which will show data records in many pages.
- Under the row groups, I have added a new row which will be the footer
  row.

What I have done so far is able to repeat the header row of the Tablix on PDF. **But I can’t repeat the footer row and don’t know how to create a footer row for the Tablix either.**

Below is the image of my report. I have added some dialog box on the image to make my issue clearer.
[image: In image for sample report]

You can help me to **create a footer row for tablix and repeat it in every page of report.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I can figure it out myself. There are steps to make it work:

- Click choose the first cell of footer row (the row that you want it
  to become footer row – it should place under a row group)
- From Row Group panel (You can right click on report to show Row Group panel), click static cell of footer row.
- Open property, and set following attributes:

  *KeepTogether: True*

  *KeepWithGroup: After*

  *RepeatOnNewPage: True*

After settings are done, this row will become the footer row of Tablix and it can repeat on every page just like header row.
[image]

Comment: I had to use KeepWithGroup: Before instead, no idea why. But thank you, you saved my day :)